# Lambda Function to convert csv to parquet from s3

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda

I have a requirement -
1. To convert parquet file present in s3 to csv format and place it back in s3. The process should exclude the use of EMR.
2. Parquet file has more than 100 cols i need to just extract 4 cols from that parquet file and create the csv in s3.

Does anyone has any solution to this?
Note - Cannot use EMR or AWS Glue

Comment: I am just listing the different ways a lambda can be triggered from s3 in the answer below. because the question is tagged as aws-lambda. There are other ways as well.

Comment: Parquet file need column types. How are you passing them to your code?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to keep things easy within the AWS environment, and not using Spark (Glue / EMR), you could use AWS Athena in the following way:

1. Let's say your parquet files are located in S3://bucket/parquet/.
2. You can create a table in the Data Catalog (i.e. using Athena or a Glue Crawler), pointing to that parquet location. For example, running something like this in the Athena SQL console:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE parquet_table (
    col_1 string,
    ...
    col_100 string)
PARTITIONED BY (date string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
LOCATION 's3://bucket/parquet/' ;
```

3. Once you can query your parquet_table table, which will be reading parquet files, you should be able to create the CSV files in the following way, using Athena too and choosing only the 4 columns you're interested in:

```
 CREATE TABLE csv_table
 WITH (
     format = 'TEXTFILE', 
     field_delimiter = ',',
     external_location = 's3://bucket/csv/'
         ) 
 AS SELECT col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4
 FROM parquet_table ;
```

After this, you can actually drop the csv temporary table and only use the CSV files, under s3://bucket/csv/, and do more, for example by having an S3-trigger Lambda function and doing something else or similar.

Remember that all this can be achieved from Lambda, interacting with Athena (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54172923/run-aws-athena-s-queries-with-lambda-function)) and also, bear in mind it has an ODBC connector and PyAthena to use it from Python, or more options, so using Athena through Lambda or the AWS Console is not the only option you have, in case you want to automate this in a different way.

I hope this helps.

Additional edit, on Sept 25th, 2019:
Answering to your question, about doing this in Pandas, I think the best way would be using Glue Python Shell, but you mentioned you didn't want to use it. So, if you decide to, here it is a basic example of how to:

```
import pandas as pd
import boto3
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv,
                          ['region',
                           's3_bucket',
                           's3_input_folder',
                           's3_output_folder'])

## @params and @variables: [JOB_NAME]
##    Variables used for now. Job input parameters to be used.
s3Bucket = args['s3_bucket']
s3InputFolderKey = args['s3_input_folder']
s3OutputFolderKey = args['s3_output_folder']

## aws Job Settings
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(s3Bucket)

for s3_object in s3_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=s3InputFolderKey):
    s3_key = s3_object.key
    s3_file = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=s3Bucket, Key=s3_key)

    df = pd.read_csv(s3_file['Body'], sep = ';')

    partitioned_path = 'partKey={}/year={}/month={}/day={}'.format(partKey_variable,year_variable,month_variable,day_variable)
    s3_output_file = '{}/{}/{}'.format(s3OutputFolderKey,partitioned_path,s3_file_name)

    # Writing file to S3 the new dataset:
    put_response = s3_resource.Object(s3Bucket,s3_output_file).put(Body=df)
```

Carlos.

Comment: Instead of using Athena or Glue Crawler. Is there an option using pandas,pyarow,S3fs or StringIO. If yes how this can be achieved?

Comment: I've just added a comment, hoping this might help you.

Comment: Thanks Carlos!! Appreciate your quick response and help!!

Answer (score 0):

- It all depends upon your business requirement, what sort of action you want to take like Asynchronously or Synchronous call.
- You can trigger a lambda [github example](https://github.com/amittn/s3-trigger-lambda) on s3 bucket asynchronously when a parquet file arrives in the specified bucket. [aws s3 doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html)
- You can configure s3 service to send a notification to SNS or SQS as well when an object is added/removed form the bucket which in turn can then invoke a lambda to process the file [Triggering a Notification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/developer-guide/s3-example-add-notification.html).
- You can run a lambda Asynchronously every 5 minutes by scheduling the [aws cloudwatch events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html) The finest resolution using a cron expression is a minute.
- Invoke a lambda Synchronously over HTTPS (REST API endpoint) [using API Gateway.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-on-demand-https.html)
- Also worth checking how big is your Parquet file as lambda can run max 15 min i.e. 900 sec.
- Worth checking this page as well [Using AWS Lambda with Other Services](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-services.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is worth taking a look at CTAS queries in Athena recently: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas-examples.html
We can store the query results in a different format using CTAS.